# Custom View for UICollectionViewCell Drag Preview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a feature where by a user drags and drops one collectionview cell onto another. However, I want to change the preview of the thing in motion completely, as to match the visual metaphor of my app (the item isn't moving, something the item contains is moving).

For example, say my collectionview cell shows a pen of pigs, and I want to to let the pig move from one pen to another, the preview view should be a view showing a single, not the pen. Its a slightly different use to what apple intended with their API, but a valid one I think.

I've seen `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters` but that just lets you clip it slightly, not re-do the whole view.

Any ideas?/Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered disabling collection view's drag drop and using your own 
implementation? You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to add your own drag review view, and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move it. Start point of long press and the end point of pan should give you the source and destination of drag and drop using `indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint)`

Answer (score 13):

Since iOS 11 you can make use of UIDragItem. There is a

```
open var previewProvider: (() -> UIDragPreview?)?
```

A simple example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
{
    ...
    let dragItem: UIDragItem = ....
    dragItem.localObject = item
    dragItem.previewProvider = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "preivewOfThingInMotion"))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64)
        return UIDragPreview(view: imageView)
    }
    return [dragItem]
}
```

As soon as you start dragging an item around the drag image will be changed to your custom view.

**Demo**

In the demo you can see two UICollectionViews. A drag & drop operation is started from the upper UICollectionView and an item is dragged to the lower one. As the item moves, a custom preview of the item is displayed.

[image]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: how to custom it when it's being lifted, i mean before it's dragging